# Cannot update or install DBus

Tags: raspbian, kernel, bluetooth

I've been trying to connect A bluetooth dongle to a bt breakout board (kernel 3.12). Both of them show up with hcitool scan and dev. I've already installed bluez5 that keeps complaining about dbus:

```
$ bluez-simple-agent hci0 20:14:03:24:37:06
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 89, in <module>
    manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
```

I've tried to re-install DBus bit I get errors at ./configure:

http://pastebin.com/tihTMxan

When trying to update dbus I get this message:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d -f dbus defaults
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (empty) of script `dbus' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: warning: script 'mathkernel' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

When trying to start dbus I get this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/sbus start
sudo: /etc/init.d/sbus: command not found
```

These problems were the same using a different SD card for boot, even though I installed everything form the scratch. The bluetooth devices show up with hcitool scan and hcitool dev. What am I missing?